# How can I get JSON data from the server by using Autobhan(Crossbar)

Tags: json, websocket, autobahn, crossbar

I got this as below from backend developer:

```
 session.publish('com.test.temp', [
        temp,
        humidity,
        componentId,
        componentType
     ], {}, { exclude_me: true });
```

So I succeed in a handshake with the server using WebSocket:

```
 var ws = new WebSocket('ws://1server address','example.json');

  ws.onopen = function () {
      console.log('websocket is connected ...')

      ws.send('connected')
  }

  ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
      console.log(ev);
  }
```

But I could not see any data in the **console.log(ev)**

How can I get JSON data from the server??

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to get data from the crossbar.

I was supposed to use autobahn library.

This is my solution:

var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
    url : 'server url',
    realm: 'realm1'
  });

connection.onopen = function (session) {

```
console.log('websocket is connected ...')

session.subscribe('com.example.example', function(message) {
 console.log(message);

 }
```

}

connection.open();

I hope this answer will be helpful to someone.